# Adding more parameters to a Linq query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm using this query to count number of orders by date. I'm trying to add one more parameter that counts total products for each order, however I can't get it to work atm.

This is the essential part of a method that is suposed to return a list of 3 parameters (Date, TotalOrders and TotalProducts). Im using a Linq query to get a list with total order for each date, im wondering how to add my third parameter to the list "TotalProducts" and if i can do by adding one more search parameter in the Query. The foreach part below do not work propertly, it will return a list of TotalProducts but CreationDate will be the same for ech item in the list. I also have a feeling putting a foreach inside a foreach dosn't seem optimal for this:

```
 var orders = _orderService.SearchOrderStatistics(startDateValue, endDateValue, orderStatus,
                paymentStatus, shippingStatus, model.CustomerEmail, model.OrderGuid);


            var result = orders.Where(o => o.PaymentStatus == PaymentStatus.Paid)
                    .GroupBy(g => g.CreatedOnUtc.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd"))
                    .Select(s => new { Date = s.Key, Count = s.Count() });



            List<GCOrdersModel> TotalOrdersPaid = new List<GCOrdersModel>();


               foreach (var g in result)
                    {

                        foreach (var opv in orders)
                        {
                            GCOrdersModel _Om = new GCOrdersModel(g.Date, g.Count.ToString(), opv.OrderProductVariants.Count.ToString());

                            TotalOrdersPaid.Add(_Om);

                        }

                    }

            return TotalOrdersPaid;
```

To access total products for every orders I must use `OrderProductVariants.Count.ToString()`

Can I add this parameter to the query?

Thx

Comment: When you say that code will give you the total products, what are you doing with it? Do you want orders with a certain number, do you want to sort by total orders, or what? If you want to *get* the total orders, then it's not so much a parameter, and more part of the return. Also, if you're after the total *number* of orders, why are you doing `.ToString()` on it? I'd advise leaving numbers as actual numbers for as long as possible; only `.ToString()` things when they absolutely *need* to be strings. Here, having them as strings makes it harder to sort/order/search by them.

Comment: so, how is `OrderProductVariants` associated with whatever `orders` is?

Comment: @anixmander - Yes i understand. However i'm using string values as im working with a Google API and this is part of a much larger context. I will refactor the code changing the datatypes accordingly later on. TotalOrdersPaid returns a list of TotalOrders by Date. What i want is to add TotalProducts as a third value to the List

Comment: @Jodrell - Var orders = _orderService.SearchOrders(Some parameters) -  foreach (var opv in orders) { TotalOrdersPaid.add(opv.OrderProductVariants.Count) } - This gives me a list of total products foreach order.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
return orders.Where(o => o.PaymentStatus == PaymentStatus.Paid)
             .GroupBy(g => g.CreatedOnUtc.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd"))
             .Select(s => new GCOrdersModel() 
                          { 
                              Date = s.Key, 
                              Count = s.Count(),
                              OpvCount = opv.OrderProductVariants.Count.ToString()
                          })
             .ToList();
```

or

```
return orders.Where(o => o.PaymentStatus == PaymentStatus.Paid)
             .GroupBy(g => g.CreatedOnUtc.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd"))
             .Select(s => new GCOrdersModel(s.Key, s.Count, opv.OrderProductVariants.Count.ToString()))
             .ToList();
```

That way, you don't have to iterate over your result again. And it automatically creates your list of `GCOrdersModel`.

**Edit**

Does this work?

```
return orders.Where(o => o.PaymentStatus == PaymentStatus.Paid)
                 .GroupBy(g => g.CreatedOnUtc.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd"))
                 .Select(s => new GCOrdersModel() 
                              { 
                                  Date = s.Key, 
                                  Count = s.Count(),
                                  OpvCount = s.OrderProductVariants.Count.ToString()
                              })
                 .ToList();
```

or

```
return orders.Where(o => o.PaymentStatus == PaymentStatus.Paid)
                 .GroupBy(g => g.CreatedOnUtc.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd"))
                 .Select(s => new GCOrdersModel(s.Key, s.Count(), s.OrderProductVariants.Count.ToString()))
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: I see but i cant do this as pov isn't declared before i use a foreach. foreach(var opv in orders) { List.add(opv,OrderProductVariants.Count) }

Comment: @KristofferAndersson What is the relation between `order` and `OrderProductVariants`? Does my edit work?

Comment: Nope didn't work. I updated the post to give more clarity to what im doing

Comment: @KristofferAndersson Does the edit of my edit work? :)

Comment: This worked: var resultOrders = orders.Where(o => o.PaymentStatus == PaymentStatus.Paid)
                    .GroupBy(g => g.CreatedOnUtc.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd"))
                    .Select(s => new GCOrdersModel(s.Key, s.Count().ToString(), s.Sum(x => x.OrderProductVariants.Count()))).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var opvCount =
    opv
        .OrderProductVariants
        .Count
        .ToString();

return
    orders
        .Where(o => o.PaymentStatus == PaymentStatus.Paid)
        .GroupBy(g => g.CreatedOnUtc.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd"))
        .Select(s => new
        {
            Date = s.Key,
            Count = s.Count()
        })
        .Select(x =>
            new GCOrdersModelg(x.Date, g.Count.ToString(), opvCount));
```

Comment: Sorry if im being unclear but opv must be declared before i create a GCOrdersModel object as it represent an order object in orders. opv was just an example on a variable that could be use to access/iterate the properties of orders within a foreach loop.